# Librebase does not start for me 20.10

Tags: libreoffice

By default, I have libreoffice installed on Kubuntu 20.10. I do not have base installed so I installed it with sudo apt install libreoffice-base. All went well up until this point. When I start base by either clicking on the icon in the menu or libreoffice --base, nothing happens. I expected to see the program start up.

Comment: Please add info from `apt-cache policy libreoffice-base` and `libreoffice --base` to the question body.

Comment: You solved it for me thanks @N0rbert, turns out the libreoffice package was not properly installed. This is strange considering I do have the core libreoffice programs available to me and they work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reinstall full LibreOffice package by:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libreoffice
```